# Part with no hose connected in engine compartment

Tags: ford, part-identification, e350

I've got a '96 Ford e350 van (5.8L V8), and after taking off the air filter box and hoses, I saw this piece:

[image]

What part is that?  And should there be a hose connected to it?

Comment: FYI the light in the background is because we took the engine cover of (inside the cab).

Comment: We need other image angles of the part.